# Is there a consensus on keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I know there are some ubiquitous shortcuts across most apps and platforms like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> for save.

But I've noticed there is a lot of inconsistency with other common functions. For example, some programs use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> for 'Save As', while others use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> (with Shift reserved for 'Save All').

So I'm wondering, is there any consensus on what functions should be mapped to which keys? I see the Shift modifier as an 'apply to all' function, with Alt as 'alternate functionality'. So I prefer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> for 'Save As' and keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> for 'Save All', 'Close All', etc.

If there isn't any consensus, should there be?

Comment: Rather subjective, but why the downvote?

Comment: this can't be worth a downvote? It is a valid question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no 'official' consensus. But software developers do want to make sure their programs are easy to use, so they tend to mimic what has been adopted as the common-practice. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will almost always be some form of copy within the context of your application, just as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> will almost always be some form of save. If you want to please your users, you make your program as familiar as possible.

Comment: ...At least on Windows. Though Linux desktop environments are following those conventions at least to a degree, you'll find that many programs on Unix do strange things -or nothing at all- on Control C / V / S

Comment: Hard to fault them, though: usually they've been using those keystrokes for years before Windows was even planned.

Comment: Yes, on Windows.

Comment: And on Macintosh (though with the Command key instead of Control) since before Windows existed.

Comment: Just something to note here. Having the "standard" bindings around is essentially about *learnability* (ease of learning), which is just a part of a program's *usability* (ease of use). Vi and Emacs (that notably have little common keys with de-facto guidelines) are generally considered super-usable, just not easy to learn.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about what developer is used to. I hate VS for killing a line on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, it does it every time when I use `C-x C-s` like I used to in Emacs.

If you are developer, my suggestion would be - make it customizable, set default with whatever most popular program in your field is using and just go on fixing bugs, they are much more important.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. There is no consensus at all, even between applications of Microsoft. It's not only that developers can choose whatever they want to implement their shortcuts, and even they can choose not to implement some of them.

Other problem is the language. In English "ctrl+S" could be a good shortcut for "Save", but for Spanish this should be "Ctrl+g" (guardar) and it is in many programs.

However, there are certain rules, as you probably know, but there are not unbreakable laws.